# strncmp function on c++

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a problem with strcmp function in c++, the compiler says "error reading characters of string" and i did used string at all.. if you can have a look i would be more then greatfull

///this is where is used the function, data is class MailAcount//

```
cout << "please enter user name: " << endl;
    char input_user[20];
    cin >> input_user;
    cout << "please enter password: " << endl;
    char input_password[20];
    cin >> input_password;

    if (!strncmp(input_user, data.GetUser(), 20) ||
        !strncmp(input_password, data.GetPassword(), 20))
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "Access confirm" << endl;
    }
```

//this is the header of MailAcount//

```
   class MailAcount
  {
      private:
         char* _email;
         char* _password;

      public:
         MailAcount(char* email,char* password);
         MailAcount();
         char* GetUser();
         char* GetPassword();
         ~MailAcount();
 };
```

//this is the cpp of MailAcount//

```
#include "MailAcount.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

MailAcount::MailAcount(char *email,char *password)
 {
     _email = email;
     _password = password;

 }

  MailAcount::MailAcount()
 {

 }

 char* MailAcount::GetUser()
 {
     return _email;
 }

 char* MailAcount::GetPassword()
{
    return _password;
}


 MailAcount::~MailAcount()
{

}
```

Comment: `input_password` is 10 characters long, including the null terminator, but you're comparing 20 characters...?

Comment: opss i was playing with the code to try and see how to solve it.. i have changed it.. thanks :)

Comment: You could just avoid any weird problems by using `std::string` instead of messing around with pointers.

Comment: Could you add the _exact_ error your compiler is giving you? (What you state doesn't sound like a compiler error.)

Comment: strncmp returns 0 if your strings match, so isnt your logic wrong?

Comment: i tried it.. didn't work either..

Comment: @ShauryaChats: Precisely. So if **either** string matches, `! strcmp` returns `true`, and `ERROR` is printed.

Comment: > The compiler says "error reading characters of string"

Which compiler is this and which line number is it producing that message?

Also, that code is so const-incorrect it hurts my eyes. And your constructor of MailAccount is liable to have your object pointing to out of scope memory.

And last, strcmp returns <0, 0, or > 0, so ! is a *really* bad operator to use on it

Comment: @Mat
can't post a photo - when i build there is no errors but when i use the debugger the program crashes and that it what the complier says

Comment: Don't see where you actually created the instance of the class you're comparing against, but just copying the pointers passed in is not likely to end well.  Use `std::string`.

Comment: That's not a compiler error at all then. The compiler isn't involved once the executable (or library) has been produced. That's a runtime error, or a debugger message. Please try and produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there's too much stuff we don't know about your code to guess at the problem, except that you're probably doing something wrong with those pointers one way or another.

Answer (score -1):

The programm crashing in the debugger is most likely due to a situation where you have not provided memory to the char's where your pointers in mail account are pointing to.

This one works

```
char myName[20]; // 20 characters on the stack
char myPwd[20]; // 20 characters on the stack
MailAccount(myName, myPwd); // ok, points to allocated memory (on the stack)
```

This one will crash

```
char* myName; // only a pointer pointing somewhere 
char* myPwd; // only a pointer pointing somewhere
MailAccount(myName, myPwd); // not ok, as the pointers will point (most likely) to non accessible memory
```

EDIT: As you tagged this as C++, you still should consider using std library strings as the commenters already suggested.
EDIT2: Corrected accoring to comment

Comment: `&variable` is always a valid pointer, although perhaps not the one you intended.